# M600-Pro Osdk with STM32 onboard

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm working with M600 Pro to make automated flight. I'm working both in simulation and real world.

One of the latest problem is using the function: `moveByPositionOffset(10, 0, zPosition, 0);`
Why It not possibile to reach more than 6 m (or -6 m) on x direction? Is there anything I have to change to move with relative position with more than that?

How can I solve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Hi, thanks, ... are considered noise](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950);

Comment: Can you update your question to say whether this behavior is only happening in simulation OR only in the real world OR both? Additionally, please also add information about 1) Whether DJI Go is connected and error free 2) If simulating, are you using the default co-ordinates?

Comment: It was a problem on timeoutInMilSec. I set it to low and the task couldn't be completed both in simulation and real world. I did that because of another. I will post in another question later. Thanks.